# send List<> values with Body in mail - SMTP server

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, smtp

I have to send mail through `SMTP` server. I can able to send it with single values. But, I want to send `List<>` values as message body in table format or some other structure. I include my code following :

```
MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com", "Reg : send mail",
"Emp Name :" + "Emp1" + Environment.NewLine + "Date From :   " + Mon + "Date To :   " + Fri);
SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", ***);
SMTPServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;
SMTPServer.Timeout = 200000;
SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("asd@gmail.com", "******");
SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
```

I have my list of values as follows :

```
List<TimesheetValues> mailBody = new SampleDAO().GetDataForMail(dt1, satDate);
```

How can I include this `List<>` values with body and send?

I try with following :

```
List<TimesheetValues> Msg = new List<TimesheetValues>(); string strMsg = ""; int n=1;
            foreach(var item in mailBody)
            {
                strMsg = strMsg + "<table><tr><td>" + n + "</td><td>" + item.Project_Name + "</td><td>" + item.Task_Name + "</td><td>" + item.Notes + "</td><td>" + item.Hrs_Worked + "</td></tr></table>";                
                n++;
            }
            strMsg = strMsg + "</br>";
             MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("abc123@gmail.com", "xyz123@gmail.com", "Reg : Timesheet",
                "Emp Name :" + "Emp1" + Environment.NewLine + "Date From :   " + Mon + "Date To :   " + Fri);            

             mailObj.Body = "Emp Name : " + "Emp1" + Environment.NewLine + "Date From :   " + Date2 + " Date To :   " + Date6 + Environment.NewLine + strMsg;
```

Now I get all records but i have tr td tags with in records and not display as a table. How can i acheive this ?

can anyone help to overcome this..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with this following  :

```
string strMsg = ""
 strMsg = timsheetMail + " <table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" border=\"1\"><tr><td> Date </td><td> Working Hours </td><td> Task </td><td>Comments</td></tr>";    

List<TimesheetValues> Msg = new List<TimesheetValues>(); int n=1;
            foreach(var item in mailBody)
            {
 timesheetData = new TimesheetDetailModel();
                timesheetData.Task_Id = matrix.Task_Id;
                timesheetData.Hours = matrix.Hours;
                //timesheetData.Date = matrix.Date.Date;
                timesheetData.Date = matrix.Date.AddDays(1);
                timesheetData.EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpId"].ToString());
                timesheetData.Notes = matrix.Notes;

                strMsg = strMsg+ " <tr><td> " + timesheetData.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</td><td>" + timesheetData.Hours + "</td><td>" + task + "</td><td>" + timesheetData.Notes +  "</td></tr>";                
                n++;
            }
            strMsg = strMsg + "</table>";
```

Its working good now..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the string into a list again, serialize is better.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourList);
mailObj.Body = json;
```

You can also deserialize in the other side:

```
List<string> g = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(body);
```